# Autoconversión de enlace a pregunta de SO no está funcionando

Tags: bug, enlaces

Recién publiqué una respuesta con un enlace a una pregunta de SO. Usualmente luego de unos instantes en la vista previa se muestra el título de la pregunta, pues en esta ocasión no funcionó ni siquiera al publicar la respuesta.

[image]

En enlace en cuestión es el siguiente:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473/1595451

Comment: mmm y aca tampoco anda... a ver...

Comment: Esto nunca ha funcionado. Los enlaces de SO no se autocompletan en SOes. Solo lo hacen los del propio SOes y, en Meta, los de Meta SE